# No Soundcard detected on laptop

Tags: audio, kubuntu

I am running Kubuntu 20.04 on a dell XPS Dev edition.

Sound used to work, but it recently stop working and no sound card is beeing detected

```
$ sudo inxi -SNA                                                                                                      
System:    Host: Kernel: 5.6.0-1013-oem x86_64 bits: 64 Console: tty 1 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel driver: sof-audio-pci 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.6.0-1013-oem 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver: iwlwifi
```

I am a bit confused as to what happened here - so, would very much appreciate some pointer !

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works now. it was a kernel issue I guess - just fiex itself